Authentication OTPs are getting expired immediately (in Australia)
We have developed an application with Firebase phone authentication and published the application in the Google Play Store for open testing.
Referred the below link for implementation.
https://rnfirebase.io/auth/phone-auth
Before uploading the bundle we tested the application with debug and release modes, we always received OTP and verified successfully. However, after we uploaded the bundle to the Google Play store people who downloaded the application in India they are able to get the OTP and verify it successfully. The people who downloaded the application in Australia are getting the OTP but when they are verifying the OTP they are getting the below error.
[auth/session-expired] The sms code has expired. Please re-send the verification code to try again.

